# How php daemon script to read up to date varaible from another file while running?

Tags: php, include, daemon

I have a PHP Daemon Script that need to run all the time.

```
<?php

include "config.php";

while (true)
{
   sleep(2);
}
?>
```

All the important variables are defined in config.php which I need to adjust often. So Everytime, I want to make changes in config.php I have to kill the daemon service and start again. I understand the config.php is outside the while loop, so I will not be read and updated even I made some changes during running.
I cannot put  include "config.php" in while loop either as it will reset all my running variable.

Is there a function or way which I can update the variable from config.php during running the script? (Eg, read the variable from config.php file like every 10 mins)?

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, you need to use cron and configured your execution.. If you run a script with while(true), php read config when initialize.

Comment: Thank you for very quick response Cuchu. I am using Daemon not cron job. can you give me more detail?

Comment: Cron: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron_(Unix)

Comment: Thank. I know what is cron job. But my company don't want to use cron job for this particular job, as it need to run every 2 seconds. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = time();
include "conf.php";
while (true) {
    if(time() - $time > 600) {
        include "conf.php";
        $time = time();
    }
}
```

If now time - last time is > 600 (10 min) refresh conf.php and set new time..

Comment: I'm busy, this is going to help but surely there is another more verbose solution :)

Comment: This is very brilliant approach. Thank you sir. :)